# What is a variation, and what does it mean for it to be differentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

The third chapter of Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* deals with variations (relevant passages included at the end), yet no formal definition is given of what a variation is, and thus I have some questions:

1. A functional seems to be defined as a map $C\to\mathbb{R}$ where $C$ is the "space of curves". How *exactly* is $C$ defined?
2. Is $C$ a normed vector space? If so, can differentiability of a functional be stated in terms of the total derivative?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: From a physicist's perspective, I'm not sure there's a one-size-fits-all answer to (1). The definition of $C$ is generally going to be something like the space of all $\mathcal{C}^n$ functions $\gamma: [t_0, t_1] \to \mathbb{R}^m$ for some $t_0$, $t_1$, $n$, and $m$.  The value of $n$ will depend on how many derivatives of the function appear in your functional (and their powers), and the value of $m$ will depend on the number of degrees of freedom of your system.  There is often (but not always) also a requirement that the endpoints of these curves be fixed.

Comment: This seems to be meant as an informal introduction to the calculus of variations. The author points to two references with "a more detailed exposition" right before your excerpt:

> A more detailed exposition can be found in "A course in the Calculus of Variations" by M. A. Lavrentiev and L. A. Lusternik, M. L., 1938, or G. E. Shilov, "Elementary Functional Analysis", MIT Press, 1974.

This section from the Wikipedia article explains what is meant by "the variation": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation

Comment: Years ago I gave a [relevant answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives/349584#349584) to a question about functional derivatives: it possibly includes all you are willing to know on these topics. Here I limit myself to point out that functionals can be defined not only on the "space of curves" but also on sets  of (hyper)surfaces and more general objects.

Comment: What you've shown is just like one of the equivalent definitions of the total derivative, except it requires that $R=O(h^2)$ instead of $R=O(h)$